# Replace Env Variables Placeholder in spring config server native mode with vault secret

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-vault

I am currently working in a scenario where I need to use spring cloud config server for centralised config management.

Previously we were using the "native" mode to store the configurations in the local filesystem. And the sensitive information like database passwords were stored in the environment variables of the client services.

But, now we want to also use "Hashicorp Vault" to store the database passwords as "secrets", and simply replace the env variable placeholders in the native files with the secret fetched from vault during the startup.

**Current Setup (only "native" mode)**

```
--resources
  --config
    --serviceA-dev.properties
```

Sample content of `serviceA-dev.properties`

```
spring.datasource.connectionProperties=jdbc:postgresql://${PG_HOST}:${PG_PORT}/${DB_NAME};username=${DB_USERNAME};password=${DB_PASSWORD}
```

**Expected Setup (both "native" & "vault" mode)**

```
--resources
  --config
    --serviceA-dev.properties
```

Sample Content of `serviceA-dev.properties`

```
spring.datasource.connectionProperties=jdbc:postgresql://${PG_HOST}:${PG_PORT}/${DB_NAME};username=${DB_USERNAME};password=${DB_PASSWORD}
```

But here instead of storing the values of `${DB_PASSWORD}` in env variables, we want to connect to vault during the startup, and then replace this with the actual value fetched from the vault

So, can this be achieved?